# Arrow function transform not transpile the arrow function that from imported modules and error in IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, arrow-functions, babel-loader

currently i have one issue for my project which is my arrow function does not get to transpile from my own imported module. I try to explain with my examples:

This is my .babelrc file

```
{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-object-assign",
    "transform-class-properties",
    "react-html-attrs",
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
    "transform-es2015-function-name",
    "transform-es2015-shorthand-properties"
  ],
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "browsers": [
            "Chrome >= 52",
            "FireFox >= 44",
            "Safari >= 7",
            "ie >= 9",
            "last 4 Edge versions"
          ]
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true,
        "debug": true
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "es2015"
  ]
}
```

and this is my package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-plugin-react-html-attrs": "^2.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.1.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  }
```

and this is my babel loader config in webpack.config

```
   module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js[x]$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
    ]
}
```

With these config, I have try two examples which is when the arrow function is in root components it did transpile the arrow function to modern javscript but when I import the function from other file and it import the arrow function inside my component and it get error in IE11.

First example that working:

```
import React from 'react';

const testing = data => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
}

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{testing("Hi, this is testing.")}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

But when I move the arrow function to other files and import to the root App it does not work in IE11 anymore and I check inside the bundle file it appears "=>" arrow function in bundle file which is not transpile to function.

Examples 2 that not get to transpile:
App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import testing from "./testing"

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>{testing("Hi, this is testing.")}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

testing.js

```
const testingFunction = data => {
    return data;
};

export default function testing(data){
    return testingFunction(data);
}
```

Arrow function transform does not transform the **example 2** **testing.jsx** testingFunction() to modern javascript

Is it anything I miss up and sorry for my broken english.
Thank you.